# How would an SMPS made using a 555 timer compare with one made with a dedicated controller?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, 555

The SMPS uses some sort of PWM to charge and discharge a magnetic element. The controller IC achieves this by using a switching element along with capacitors. While one could theoretically use 555 timers to create an SMPS, this is not usually done as that would require extra work to make the circuit work.

If one used 555 timers to make an SMPS, what challenges would one face and why would the performance of such an SMPS be worse than one created using dedicated controller IC? Using 555 timers, it should be possible to get PWM at several hundred kHz easily, I think.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not that hard to make a proper (in this case peak current mode) control with one.  It's just more bother than it's worth, and still much poorer performing than buying a chip with all those block diagram elements already integrated, e.g. UC3843.

https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/555%20Boost.pdf 
<sup>(Disclosure: my website. Not embedding to conserve copyright.)</sup>

This is an example how to use one.  Peak current mode control is implemented by monitoring switch (Q1) current at R13, using a common-base amplifier (Q3) to amplify and level-shift the signal to the `THR`eshold voltage range (which equals `CTR` voltage).  `CTR` in turn is driven by the error amplifier IC2, which sets the switch peak current so as to regulate output voltage.

It's been some years as you can see, and I forget exactly why D2 is there; something about compensating for Q2's V<sub>BE</sub> drop, or the `TRG` threshold (half the `CTR` voltage, by internal resistor divider).  I also forget if this was frequency-variable, or compensated in such a way that frequency is fairly stable; in that case the resistor and diode act to set a typical RC time constant (which therefore gives a consistent off-time delay, if not frequency overall, by similar reasoning as the 555's basic operation -- that is, by voltage ratios and RC time constants, rather than, say, constant currents and threshold voltages).

The circuit does work, but adjusting it for other supply or output voltages is left as the proverbial exercise for the student.  You will also notice many relatively low-value resistors, besides the 555's own supply current consumption (not to mention output shoot-through current!): this is not an especially efficient circuit, and even an old controller like UC3842 easily beats it in terms of control power.

---

One could equally well make an average current mode control, using a pair of 555s (or one 556) as ramp generator then PWM comparator.  Current and voltage error amps would then be added, in nested loops respectively, to set PWM based on current setpoint, and current setpoint based on voltage setpoint, to obtain regulated output (or, really, whatever else you want to regulate to).

But you're again using a whole pile of components, when a TL494 has the oscillator and one error amp inside already (among other features).  (Notice although TL494 has dual error amps, they are wired-OR, not cascaded, so an external voltage error amp is required for the nested-loop configuration.)  It also supports push-pull operation (max <50% duty cycle per output, alternating between two outputs).  Or if you prefer totem-pole style outputs, TL598 has these, comparable to 555's output pin but without nearly so much shoot-through.

To be clear, these are excellent didactic opportunities; and not much more than that.  (Other good exercises are reproducing UC3843, TL494, etc. from comparators, op-amps and digital logic (gates, flip-flops).  In fact, you can use faster components and make one run at some MHz, whereas these parts are confined below about 500kHz and 100kHz, respectively.)  There's just absolutely no reason to ever do this on a PC board in a real production item.  For that matter, there's little enough reason to use 3843, 494, etc. as it is...

Comment: @Marcus: StackOverflow terms and conditions prohibit you from posting content without the rightsholder's permission.  Which here was explicitly denied.

Comment: It has also been cached on archive.org, if poor availability is feared: https://web.archive.org/web/20221026002512/https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/555%20Boost.pdf

Comment: Maybe it could help a person learn more about the SMPS theory right?

Comment: @quantum231 Like I said, "excellent didactic opportunities" :)

Comment: Note that the link to your personal website is partially down. Connections over IPv6 timeout after 30 seconds, connections over IPv4 work. Some people that are in IPv6 only networks are unable to use it, as the website includes an IPv6 record, so IPv4 transitional techniques are not tried

Comment: @Ferrybig Thanks -- alas I don't have any way to get alerts on that.

Comment: @TimWilliams Someone or something has misconfigured your DNS. You'll either have to fix it if the records were written by you directly, or complain to the hosting provider for having bogus DNS records that impair connectivity to your site. I don't think you need alerts for this: once it's configured correctly, it'll hopefully stay that way.

Comment: Manually configured, yeah. It was my understanding IPv6 isn't supposed to change, but somewhere in the intervening time a block of it had changed (something about the host ISP perhaps?), go figure.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm sorry about the inclusion of the image. I didn't mean to counteract your copyright at all! It is my understanding that I didn't, though: copyright of course stays with you, and while content posted to SE gets a cc-by-sa license, that of course cannot apply to citations (if I cite the Lord of the Rings, that didn't put LOTR under CC-by-SA. Same goes for showing how something is done in the Linux kernel by posting a code excerpt). I'd argue that with the link above, that picture was a clearly marked quote. Anyways, it's your schematic, and it's a decision that's yours to 1/2

Comment: ... make, so, again, my apologies. Hope you're not too upset about it! @BenVoigt Thanks, see comment above 2/2